# LaTeX fails to compile due to Umlauts

Tags: compiling, input-encodings, german

I am fairly new to LaTeX, so please bear with me! :)

So my problem is the following: I have a LaTeX document with several subsections. I write in German, so I have to use Umlauts. Using them normally without the \"u trick worked fine, but now after line 246 LaTeX fails to compile because of the Umlauts. The first ~240 lines are ok though. I am using inputenc and fontenc. The document itself is in UTF-8, just like the setting for my inputenc.

I really have no idea what could have caused this, why the problem only occurs in a few lines, and why it does not apply to the whole document (and also why LaTeX stops compiling altogether!).

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: No way to find out what's wrong without more information. I'm as well writing in German with every ÄäÖöÜü and ß, but no issue. So there is something else. With you MWE please provide some info on your installation (OS, texlive YY, or MiKTeX?, fully updated?).

Comment: I vote to close as offtopic because the error was a typo and no future user will have any benefit from this question.

Answer (score 1):

Ok you can call me stupid now. After trying different stuff for hours I realized that instead of `\end{lstlisting}` I wrote `\end{lslisting}`. The problem was a missing 't'. I am sorry.

Comment: No, at least I won't call you whatever. This is a typical mistake of a beginner. For using LaTeX it is advisable to have a systematical way of searching for errors. Maybe next time start something called "bisecting": Comment out the second half of your text (but take care to get all environments closed). Error still there? Comment out the second quarter of the text. Error gone? Must be somewhere in the second quarter. Bisect the second quarter: Comment out its second half. (Ähm, won't really help in all cases, some weeks ago I was pointed here to a really idiotic mistake, won't tell where...).

Comment: +1 for your answer here, but please don't ask questions without a MWE again. Beginners really often find the error while trying to put an MWE together. And we here can't help you without MWE, at least in most cases.